# Incompatible types error with ArrayList

Tags: java, types, arraylist

In my Java class I have this property defined:

```
private ArrayList requests;
```

and this is the constructor in the class:

```
public LeaveRecord() {
    this.requests = new ArrayList<Request>();
    this.daysLeft = ALLOWANCE;
}
```

in another method I'm trying to return the relevant `Request` object based on the index of the ArrayList.

```
public Request getRequestAt(int index) {
    try {
        return this.requests.get(index);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

but I'm getting an error on the return line (line 3 in the above snippet) that says it requires `leaverecord.Request` but found `java.lang.Object`.

I don't know what could be wrong, as I defined the ArrayList to be of type `Request`.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change it to

```
private ArrayList requests;

private ArrayList<Request> requests
```

However compiler should have show you the below warning when you say

```
 private ArrayList requests;
```

`ArrayList is a raw type. References to generic type ArrayList<E> should be 
     parameterized`

Comment: Or possibly `List<Request>` (to reduce coupling and code to the interface). And maybe make it `final`. The old code should have generated a compiler warning, too, about missing type annotations.